# Url redirection Help for magento 2

Tags: magento2, redirect-url

I need some help for url redirection in Magento 2. I want to show my own url in the address bar but the page should be from another url.

For example, if the link is `www.xyz.com/blog/post/post.html`, then I want it changed to `www.xyz.com/post.html` in the address bar. How can I achieve this?

Comment: using routing mechanism of magento

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Url Rewrite** for your requirement.
In Magento admin goto Marketing->SEO & Search->and tap URL Rewrites.
Click “Add URL Rewrite” button.
In `Request path` add `blog/post/post.html`
In `Target Path` add `post.html`
Select `Redirect Type` as `Permanent (301)`

[image]

That's it.

Comment: this redirection is not working for me @Rizwan

Comment: want to show only /post.html but it is still showing /blog/post/post.html after redirection

Comment: post.html showing 404 error.Can I point the post to post.html instead of /blog/post.html.

Comment: I am using better blog extension.

Comment: Yes, you can try post to post.html instead of /blog/post.html.

Comment: also can you change redirect try to 302.